# Render layer confusion

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I'm trying to composite a shockwave effect with the blender render engine.
My scene is currently set up with two render layers:

Layer one: Text, two lamps and a camera.
Layer two: shockwave.

I have two issues currently, however I think the first issue may be beyond the scope of this question, I'm not entirely sure if it's something to do with the layer comp.

Issue One: The shockwave colouring seems not to be working from certain frames. Even though nothing is keyframed, everything seems to desaturate from frame 40 to about frame 100.

Issue Two: The final render is rendering the shockwave layer in front of the text when the object is behind the text. If I switch the alpha mix over node's inputs none of the actual shockwave renders, only the text layer.

[Download the Blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njqjydj9sgxfkwg/intro.blend?dl=0)

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Please post your blend or at least screen shots so we can help you further.

Comment: added the .blend

Comment: Doesn't seem to download for me. Clicking the download button does nothing. I'll try again later.

Comment: I've changed it to a dropbox link now, that should work.

Comment: Ok, got it. Everything seems to be on one layer. I thought you were compositing 2 layers together?

Comment: that's odd, my blend here has the text on layer one and the shockwave on layer two. the render layers "text" is using layer one and "shockwave" is using layer two. the shockwave on layer two is visible at around frame 60

Comment: Nope, in my file there is one viewport layer in use and one render layer in use. Also, your shockwave material is using Cycles nodes but your render engine is set to Blender Render. Which engine do you intend to use?

Comment: Blender render engine is what I want to use. seems like something has happened to the .blend when I sent it to you. Let me just check and reupload it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/njqjydj9sgxfkwg/intro.blend?dl=0 is the new blender file.

Comment: Ok, that's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are a number of issues with your file:

1. Select Layers 1 and 2 in the viewport to have both layers render.

[image]

2. In the **Render>Shading** panel you should select **Transparent** instead of **Sky** for the Alpha setting. This will allow your Text layer to render with an alpha channel instead of black.

[image]

3. Secondly, your Hue/Sat compositing node affecting the Shockwave layer IS keyframed on the Value field. Try muting it to see the difference.

[image]

4. Reverse the inputs on your Alpha Over node to put the shockwave behind.

[image]

[image]

The shockwave image is very light when viewing in Color+Alpha mode in the UV/Image Editor. If you switch to Color only you can see a stronger effect. Alternatively, you could composite a black background behind everything to see it better.

[image]

Comment: Changing the shading alpha to Transparent has just given me a full blank image.

Comment: What are you looking at when you see the blank image? The Render Result or the Viewer node in the Compositor? Check your individual render layers to see what is rendering for each layer.

Comment: I'm looking at Render result.

Comment: Could be your composite node is giving a blank image, but the render layers are correct. You can change the view in the Render Result to just see each Render Layer output separately. What does that show?

Comment: Also, your text layer was not selected in your original blend, so you may have to select that to get it to render.

Comment: Updated answer to be more complete.

Comment: I've added the render output that I'm getting to the OP so you can see.

Comment: Probably the alpha over node inputs. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: Still baffled about the shockwave though. The tutorial I watched used that keyframe for fading the shockwave out at the end. Yet having that keyframe messes up the start of the shockwave even though the frames before that have the same values. removing the keyframe fixes it, but still leaves me confused about how I'm going to actually fade the shockwave out.

Comment: You can re-enable the HueSat node, but you have to duplicate the key at frame 188 and move it to frame 1, so that it has a starting value.